# Facebook and PHP

Tags: php

Isn't PHP less efficient compared to other languages?  I think there are better options out there.

Do you think Facebook will abandon PHP? (just like Twitter partly left Ruby on Rails)

I just wanted to hear your opinion.

Comment: My crystal ball says... "Question is subjective and argumentative".

Comment: not optimized for large websites??? Facebook, Twitter, Wikipedia...?? Just wrong...

Comment: you should put your question at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you think Facebook will seek for other language after customizing the application so far now ? ? I don't think they will migrate.

Comment: I agree this discussion not suitable for stackoverflow.com. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're making a pretty big assumption saying that PHP is not optimized for large web sties. There are plenty of mechanisms to make pretty much any language work for any size web site. These mechanisms generally fall into one of two categories

- Caching
- Horizontal scaling

With that said, I don't think Facebook will abandon PHP. The amount of work to re-write functionality just does not make business sense. New functionality or ventures may be written in different languages (Ruby, C#, Java, Scala are possibilities).

Answer (score 4):

Facebook does not use a traditional LAMP stack.

Have a look at HBase,Tornado,Cassandra,hiphop , all used by facebook.

Comment: If that's the traditional LAMP, What da hell have I been doing all these years?? :)

Answer (score 0):

PHP can be used for large portals. Yahoo! and many other does it. In fact if you configure your server (and PHP) properly you can do anything with PHP.

For XXL website what matters is the network layer to quickly scale to the requirement. So PHP is not blocker for scaling.

PHP is big plus for large websites where lot of frontend boxes are required. PHP can run on commodity boxes and so you can put lot of machines for scaling.

Maintaining security is little tricky with PHP but big guns like Yahoo!, Facebook, Google know how to secure PHP and so it is very easy to get going with PHP. (Looks like Microsoft is also interested in PHP).

Secondly, it is not easy to move from one technology to other for large websites and that might be the biggest reason why Facebook wouldn't abandon PHP.